# Invalid template file when executing cron by command

Tags: magento2

I'm executing cron job by command

```
 php -dmemory_limit=-1 ./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run
```

The cron is sending a quote reminder email, the quote is very similar to an order 
I got this error on console:

```
Invalid template file: 'Magento_OfflinePayments::info/pdf/purchaseorder.phtml' in module: 'Magento_OfflinePayments' block's name: 'info\purchaseorder_0'
```

I checked this file Magento_OfflinePayments::info/pdf/purchaseorder.phtml and it exists in vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/adminhtml/templates/info/pdf/purchaseorder.phtml

Comment: Something wrong with your project. Move that template to base

Comment: what do you mean by move template to base?